# Is there a wrapper for HTML5 sessionStorage that provides a good compatability implementation?

Tags: javascript, html, storage, session-storage

We would like to use the HTML5 sessionStorage (or something like it) in a new project but you can't rely on it on some browsers. There's this project (http://code.google.com/p/sessionstorage/) which provides an implementation that works a lot of places, yet oddly it doesn't use the HTML5 version if it is available. It always does its own thing.

There's this project (https://github.com/jas-/jQuery.handleStorage) over on GitHub 
<del>but its emulation layer is cookies (bleh!)</del>.

**Note: The above is incorrect, see the answer from jas- below where he explains that I was mistaken about that project.**

Is there anything better out there that offers a good implementation like the first project but falls back automatically to HTML5 if it is available? We might retrofit the first project to automatically fall back to HTML5 if available but would rather not build that if there's already a good solution out there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript wrapper for Google Gears / HTML5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889583/javascript-wrapper-for-google-gears-html5)

Comment: No, definitely not a duplicate. That one is about commonality between Google Gears and HTML5. We need solutions that work for more than just those two subsets of users. The StorageLite that robertc mentioned is actually ideal, it has fallbacks for many different browsers that use other mechanisms. I'll probably look at that and see if the overhead of having YUI3 is low enough we won't care or if we can port it to jQuery instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing more research on this because I liked both of the answers I got, but I wanted something more like the YUI 3: Storage Lite but that didn't require YUI. Something that was framework agnostic or jQuery friendly would work a lot better for us.

In the end I found a couple of possibilities and one stood out as what we'll try and put to use: [Lawnchair](http://westcoastlogic.com/lawnchair/)

Also considered: [store.js](https://github.com/marcuswestin/store.js), [AmplifyJS](http://amplifyjs.com/)

Comment: would love to know why you choose Lawnchair over AmplifyJS?

Comment: -1 Your chosen solution seems to not match the criteria of your original question: It seems to me that all 3 mentioned options don't support session-based storage, only persistent storage that stays also across sessions (such as localStorage and UserData). store.js even mentions it specifically: https://github.com/marcuswestin/store.js#no-sessionstorageauto-expiration. I realize this is your own solution but as a SO item for others to learn from I must downvote it (at least until the original question is updated).

Answer (score 1):

I know you said that you wanted a solution that did it all but what's wrong with something like this?

```
if(!window.sessionStorage){
    $.getScript("/google_code_sessionStorage.js");
}
```

Comment: True enough. If the emulation is a good one (and I haven't yet compared the methods side-by-side) then we could do the test, load the code, and assign an instance of the normal Storage object or the emulator to a variable and be happy ever after with only a few lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of YUI utilities for this, depending on whether you're using 2 or 3:

- [YUI 2: Storage Utility](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/storage/)
- [YUI 3: Storage Lite](http://yuilibrary.com/gallery/show/storage-lite)

Both will use HTML5 session storage if available.

Comment: We're not using YUI for anything at present, we're using jQuery for everything. But those look like excellent solutions. Especially Storage Lite and it's wide ranging set of emulations. That's impressive.

Comment: @JohnMunsch YUI2 is a bit monolithic, but YUI3 has a load of options for dynamic loading and minimal delivery so you can [just load the bits of it you need](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/yui/#use)

Answer (score 1):

Munsch,

I realize this post is several years old but I wanted to clarify the project you mentioned, I am the author of [jQuery.handleStorage](https://github.com/jas-/jQuery.handleStorage) and it does not use cookies as its default method of client storage.

If you read the documentation for the project you will see that one of its three client storage options is to use cookies in the event a clients browser does not support the HTML5 localStorage and/or sessionStorage API's.

With that said, if you need a more robust and flexible client storage tool I would recommend [secStore.js](https://github.com/jas-/secStore.js) as it does not implicitly require binding to a form, supports the HTML5 client storage options, gracefully degrades to cookie in the event of a legacy browser and optionally uses the [SJCL](http://bitwiseshiftleft.github.io/sjcl/) API to provide transparent encryption of possible sensitive data.

Comment: My apologies for misunderstanding your project, I'll edit to clarify above. Also, thank you for adding an answer even though this is a really old question, I know from experience people still hit these old questions and get help from them. As for me, I no longer have a need for this myself, all of the browsers we support now also support both localStorage and sessionStorage so it's easy to deal with caching data locally now.

Comment: No worries, one thing I should do for both is to remove the jQuery dependencies.